# Is it compulsory to use domain-relative resource URLs while using <mvc:resources>?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

package

```
             --> WebContent 
                 --> common
                     --> header.jsp
                 --> main
                     --> login.jsp
                 --> resources
                     --> css
                         --> header.css
                 --> WEB-INF
                     --> myapp-servlet.xml
                     --> web.xml
```

resource mapping defined in myapp-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:resources  mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"  cache-period="24545445"/>
```

if I use below login link  in my header.jsp

```
<a href="../main/login.jsp" >Login </a>
```

then tomcat throws Error 404 resource not found.

but when I use

```
<a href="<c:url value="/main/login.jsp"/>">Login</a>
```

it works fine.

is there any compulsion to use domain-relative resource URLs if we use mvc:resources to load the static resources in spring mvc web app ?

.

Comment: What resource isn't found, the login page? Because that basically is how the web works ...

Comment: yes login page is not found

Comment: That is how the web works. The href is basically appended to the URL in the address bar... It isn't calculated based on the file it is located in. Basic knowledge of URLs and how http/html works that is. To answer your question no but you have to think about the URLs you create and using JSTL makes that easier. And this has nothing to do with the fact that you use `<mvc:resources />`.

Comment: Then you must ne adding something else too, or forgot to add `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />`. Nonetheless writing relative URLs will eventually become a pain and you really want to use the `url` tag to help you with that (be it the default JSTL or Spring tag). Also as you are using Spring you should actually not even be referencing JSP pages directly but hide them and access them through the `DispatcherServlet`.